# How to slice image in React Native Expo?

Tags: image, react-native, expo, slice

I'm new to React Native. I want to slice a image. How can I do it in Expo?

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OUUR.png)

[Slices Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eev2d.png)

Comment: You can create 2 more views with position absolute and place on image view like 1 view on bottom and another view on bottom right with background color black so this way you can achieve